# How close can two questions be without being duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Suppose two questions are distinct but elicit similar answers, say:

According to the Protestant viewpoint, what is the origin of God?

According to the Protestant viewpoint, does God have a creator?

Short and concise answers for these two questions will likely be different ("God has always existed" and "God had no creator"), have different implications, and use different proof texts. However, as answers become longer and more detailed, it's likely that they will overlap, perhaps significantly.

Would these questions be considered "duplicates" or "related"?

Comment: By the way you might find looking at [meta posts sorted by link-back frequency](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) will point out some of the highlights as far as discussions in the history of the site go that are probably worth reading to get your head around the way things are here. The [meta-tag:faq] ones are another place to review.

Answer (score 3):

I think the litmus test in this case would actually be the more in depth answer. We are trying to optimize for detailed responses that throughly treat the subject matter of the question (incidentally this is why many questions are two broad for this format: in depth answers would not fit). Concise is good, but shortness in itself if not a huge value here.

If a through treatment of ether question will completely cover both cases then the questions are likely a duplicate. If one of the questions specifically asks about nuances that are not covered in the scope of the other question then it is probably not a  duplicate even if they cover some of the same ground. In fact we might edit such a question to specifically *not* cover the same general ground an only focus on the aspect that is unique.